# python and fast lookups of a tree where nodes have multiple attrubutes and values

Tags: python, tree, hashtable, binary-tree, binary-search-tree

I need a tree object in python that is very fast.  Speed of the lookup is more important than memory.  The leaf node is the value that I want.
So, if given state=NY, postion=3, hourOfDay=2 and dayOfWeek=3 I need to get the value =100 with speed.  The nodes with a * are a leaf node.

```
0) root
    1) {state: [NY,LA]}
        2) {howOfDay:[1,2,3,4,5], postion:[1,2,3]}
                             *3) {dayOfWeek:[234]} => value:100
            4) {state: [FL,NV,……rest of the states]}
                5) {howOfDay:[1,6,7,8,9….23]}
                      *6) {dayOfWeek:[1,5,6,7]} => value:120
```

In my database my data looks like this with the attributes as json objects.

```
parent child attribute value

0 1 state NY,LA
1 2 {howOfDay:[1,2,3,4,5], postion:[1,2,3]}
2 3 dayOfWeek dayOfWeek [2,3,4] 100
0 3 state  [FL,NV,……rest of the states]
4 5 howOfDay:[1,6,7,8,9….23]
5 6 dayOfWeek:[1,5,6,7] 120
```

So, what python library and tree structure should i use to best find a value?  How do a convert the data to best do a fast lookup?

Comment: unless the tree is too big, you should stick with `dict`

Comment: The tree will be rather big.  I should say I need a memory efficient tree structure but of the most memory effiiet...choose the one that has the best performance in lookups.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you value speed over memory you can put all you data into a dictionaly, using a `tuple(state, position, hourOfDay, dayOfWeed)` as key.

```
data = dict()
```

Now, for each leave node, insert the data into the dictionary:

```
data[state, position, hourOfDay, dayOfWeed] = value
```

You then access data using

```
value = data[state, position, hourOfDay, dayOfWeed]
```

This is faster than any tree traversal as it uses the underlying optimized CPython implementation of a hashed dictionary.

Comment: Can can you shoe me how to create the tuple with a dict?

Comment: simple : `d[(1,2,3,4)] = 'foo'`

Comment: >>> d[(1,2,3,4)] = 'foo'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'd' is not defined